# Are the lines of a file indexed?

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing the following:

```
aReader = New StreamReader(fileName)
Do Until aReader.EndOfStream
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("line {0}", aReader.ReadLine))
Loop
```

To show which line I'm on I could do:

```
aReader = New StreamReader(fileName)
Dim i As Integer = 0
Do Until aReader.EndOfStream
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("line {0}:{1}", i.ToString, aReader.ReadLine))
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Is each line in the file indexed? Is `i` required above or can I use a built in property of the `file` or the `streamReader` ?

Comment: Lines in files are not indexed (at least, not in conventional filesystems...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth...so the above second code snippet is as good as it gets if, for some reason, I needed to know a lines relative position in the file?

Comment: Unless the lines are fixed-length, pretty much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such property in a FileStream, but,
if your file is not very big you could use

```
 Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
```

and then you have an array in memory that can be easily indexed

```
 Dim aLine = lines(lines.Count - 1)
```